# Can I reset my privacy settings on OS X Mountain Lion like I can on iOS 6?

Tags: macos, privacy, geolocation

iOS allows me to reset my location settings, causing apps to have to ask me again if they can use my location information. iOS 6 allows me to reset all location and privacy settings globally as well:

[image]

Can I do the same with OS X Mountain Lion's Privacy tab in Security & Privacy? I can't seem to find any option to reset these settings (not even in the Advanced menu).

Answer (score 1):

You can't reset your settings to the defaults/empty, but you can remove specific apps from access to your location information, Twitter account, Facebook account, etc., as it sounds like you've already seen in the Security & Privacy pane of System Preferences.

You can uncheck individual apps with access to remove their access to your contacts, Twitter, or Facebook accounts; in the case of your Facebook and Twitter accounts, you can remove them from your computer altogether from the Mail, Contacts, and Calendars pane. This will essentially revert your settings to the way they were when you got Mountain Lion, since many of these features did not exist prior to OS X 10.8.